# Are all server cabinet side panels removable?

Tags: networking

I have a hp j1487b and I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the side pannels. The brackets holding them on to the frame looks like it could possibly be welded to the panel as there's nothing on the other side of the panel. It's for home use and I got it for $50, so I have no problem using brute force if I *have* to, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Not all Cabinets do, some our our smaller ones at work are a full unit apart from the door. There would normally be a key/latch holds the panel in place if the panel is removable. I cant find a good picture/Manual for that model, so can't tell you for definate

Comment: @Lister this eBay listing has a few pics of the unit. It looks like it should come off. http://m.ebay.ca/itm/272540089740

Comment: We can't tell from a picture.  **Contact the seller**. Of course one picture literally shows the door taken off.  I still advise you to contact the seller of the item.

Comment: lol, you got it for $50, when companies sell them new @ around $2k.....talk about a steal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out for anyone who may want to remove the side panels on this model: Two torx t-25 screws under each side panel lift and remove.